# How do I update the values of a switch case in Svelte

Tags: javascript, meteor, switch-statement, svelte

I am able to get the details, they are already being imported, but when I edit and submit, it doesn't take. The right information is being displayed in the options and it's showing that the new value gets submitted, but It's not updating the details. I'm not sure what is wrong.

```
    export let details;
    const handleSubmit = (event) => {
    const target = event.target;

    const values = {
      TaskFacility: target.TaskFacility.value,
      name: target.name.value,
      inspector: target.inspector.value,
      desc: target.details.value, 
      type: target.inspectionClass.value
    };

    if(values.type){
      switch(values.type){
        case 'annual':
          details.annual = true;
          details.quarterly = false;
          details.monthly = false;
          details.weekly = false;
          seriesPossible = true;
          break;
        case 'quarterly':
          details.quarterly = true;
          details.annual = false;
          details.monthly = false;
          details.weekly = false;
          seriesPossible = true;
          break;
        case 'monthly':
          details.monthly = true;
          details.quarterly = false;
          details.annual = false;
          details.weekly = false;
          seriesPossible = true;
          break;
        case 'weekly':
          details.weekly = true;
          details.quarterly = false;
          details.annual = false;
          details.monthly = false;
          seriesPossible = true;
          break;
        case 'none':
          details.weekly = false;
          details.quarterly = false;
          details.annual = false;
          details.monthly = false;
          seriesPossible = false;
          break;
      }
    }
Meteor.call('updateInspectionDetails', details._id, values, (error) => {
            if(error){
              Swal.fire('ERROR', error.message, 'error');
            } else{
              Swal.fire({
                title: "Details Updated!",
                icon: "success"
              }).then((result) => {
                if(result.value){
                  editDetails = false;
                  location.reload();
                }
              });
            }
          });
        }
      }).catch(err => errors = extractErrors(err));
  };
```

There is validate code in between the switch case and the Meteor.call. (if I need to post that I will)
This is the html:

```
<div class="form-group col-sm-12 col-md-6">
              <label for="inspectionClass">Choose Inspection Type *</label>
              <select name="inspectionClass" id="inspectionClass" class="form-control" >
                <option value="" diabled>Choose Inspection Type *</option>
                {#if details.annual || details.quarterly || details.monthly || details.weekly}
                  {#if details.annual}
                  <option value="annual" selected>Annual</option>
                  {/if}
                  {#if details.quarterly}
                  <option value="quarterly" selected>Quarterly</option>
                  {/if}
                  {#if details.monthly}
                  <option value="monthly" selected>Monthly</option>
                  {/if}
                  {#if details.weekly}
                  <option value="weekly" selected>Weekly</option>
                  {/if}
                  {:else}
                  <option value="none" selected>None</option>
                {/if}
                  <option value="none">None</option>
                  <option value="annual">Annual</option>
                  <option value="quarterly">Quarterly</option>
                  <option value="monthly">Monthly</option>
                  <option value="weekly">Weekly</option>
              </select>
            </div>
```

And the method:

```
updateInspectionDetails: (detailsId, updateObj) => {
    if(detailsId)
      InspectionDetails.update(detailsId, {
        $set: updateObj
      });
    }
  },
```

Logged Details:

```
TaskFacility: "8zAeRMdxkH7xdj7pS"
annual: false
clientId: "g34xP9xKyWHGEDevy"
createdAt: Mon Feb 15 2021 10:38:30 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time) {}
duration: "1.5"
inspectionSigned: false
inspector: "XYtN6Ph7RNy7g26Y7"
inspectorImage: false
monthly: true
name: "Monthly"
published: true
quarterly: false
startDate: Mon Feb 22 2021 11:00:00 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time) {}
taskId: "JCdbBuGak3CvTYyPs"
weekly: false
_id: "WQ6cp6LZpSnncEiQ8"
```

And every time I try to "bind" the value, it's undefined. What am I missing?
Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

You need to initialize the `details` with some value - if you don't, then it's `undefined`, so you cannot set any of it's keys.

[Here's a Svelte REPL to demonstrate](https://svelte.dev/repl/8a7b11b8c70e4558ad7d9969e59c2ab9?version=3.46.4)